# Dart 1.14 - querySelector not found

Tags: iframe, dart

Before 1.14 that code has been working `_frame.contentWindow.document.querySelector("#fileList").style.display = "none";`

Where _frame is the IFrameElement

Now I have error: `NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'querySelector'`
So I don't know how to access elements in frames.

Comment: Frame and Window were quite broken in Dart and Dartium. I don't know if this is fixed yet.